# How to query the next record after a specific one in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following data in SQL Server and I need to develop a logic that will fetch any transactions that has an **Return** right afterwards. In the below data I need to ignore(FILTER) **2nd** and **4th** records, as they have return on immediately subsequent records.https://sqlize.online/s/yi

```
INSERT INTO Table1
    (`acct_name`, `id_no`, `cube_id`, `accnt_number`, `Tran_Dt`, `Post_Dt`, `Description`, `Trcd`, `Amt`)
VALUES
    ('TEST1', 2607269, 299933445, 1999957778, '2023-04-05 00:00:00', '2023-04-05 00:00:00', 'ITEM RETURN', 'R9P', '700-01-01 00:00:00'),
    **('TEST1', 1965041, 299933445, 1999957778, '2023-04-05 00:00:00', '2023-04-05 00:00:00', 'CASHBACK XFR', 'W8', '700-01-01 00:00:00'),**
    ('TEST2', 2607269, 288833446, 2999957776, '2023-04-06 00:00:00', '2023-04-06 00:00:00', 'ITEM RETURN', 'R9P', '900-01-01 00:00:00'),
    **('TEST2', 2607269, 288833446, 2999957776, '2023-04-06 00:00:00', '2023-04-06 00:00:00', 'CASHBACK XFR', 'W8', '900-01-01 00:00:00'),**
    ('TEST3', 3607867, 199929599, 8779597774, '2023-04-06 00:00:00', '2023-04-06 00:00:00', 'WEBXFR  PYMT', 'W8', '400-01-01 00:00:00')
;
```

desired output

```
 ('TEST1', 2607269, 299933445, 1999957778, '2023-04-05 00:00:00', '2023-04-05 00:00:00', 'ITEM RETURN', 'R9P', '700-01-01 00:00:00'),     
        ('TEST2', 2607269, 288833446, 2999957776, '2023-04-06 00:00:00', '2023-04-06 00:00:00', 'ITEM RETURN', 'R9P', '900-01-01 00:00:00'),
        ('TEST3', 3607867, 199929599, 8779597774, '2023-04-06 00:00:00', '2023-04-06 00:00:00', 'WEBXFR  PYMT', 'W8', '400-01-01 00:00:00')
;
```

Comment: How do you define "next"? Tables are generally an unordered set of data. You define order by adding indexes and imposing business logic on top of them. Given the data you've added to the question what attribute (or collection of attributes) defines that the 1st record is first, that the 2nd is second and so on?

Comment: Please actually show your desired results (in addition to describing them).

Comment: Your SQL looks more like MySQL than SQL Server? Which are you using?

Comment: [Amt] column is not a datetime nor an amount.  "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."  This is probably why when I try to run the code at https://sqlize.online/s/yi it does nothing.

Comment: [accnt_number] is not in the range of an int.  Max allowable int value is 2,147,483,647.  You provided DDL example code of 2,999,957,776; 2,999,957,776; 8,779,597,774.